# How to obtain locao IP address for Docker container using Local DHCP

Tags: docker

I have Core OS/Docker running on bare metal servers.

Core OS gets its IP address on the local network over DHCP.

How do I make Docker containers bridge to the local network and 
obtain locally visible IP addresses over a DHCP server